# Build OpenJDK 9 in CentOS5

Tags: java, makefile, redhat-openjdk

I was trying to build OpenJDK 9 in Centos 5. I used

```
sh ./configure --disable-warnings-as-errors
make all
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Building target 'all' in configuration 'linux-x86_64-normal-server-release'
/root/jdk9/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server- 
release/support/native/java.base/libjava/io_util_md.o: In function 
`handleSetLength':
/root/jdk9/jdk/src/java.base/unix/native/libjava/io_util_md.c:228: 
undefined reference to `fallocate64'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/bin/objcopy: '/root/jdk9/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server- 
release/support/modules_libs/java.base/libjava.so': No such file
gmake[3]: *** [/root/jdk9/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server- 
release/support/modules_libs/java.base/libjava.so] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [java.base-libs] Error 2

ERROR: Build failed for target 'all' in configuration 'linux-x86_64-normal- 
server-release' (exit code 2)

=== Output from failing command(s) repeated here ===
* For target support_native_java.base_libjava_BUILD_LIBJAVA_link:
/root/jdk9/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server- 
release/support/native/java.base/libjava/io_util_md.o: In function 
`handleSetLength':
/root/jdk9/jdk/src/java.base/unix/native/libjava/io_util_md.c:228: 
undefined reference to `fallocate64'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

* All command lines available in /root/jdk9/build/linux-x86_64-normal- 
server-release/make-support/failure-logs.
=== End of repeated output ===

No indication of failed target found.
Hint: Try searching the build log for '] Error'.
Hint: See common/doc/building.html#troubleshooting for assistance.

make[1]: *** [main] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I also tried other make targets such as make images and make install. But still getting the same error. My GCC version is gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 which I manually installed because Centos 5 by default has an older version.

Comment: Centos5 released 12 April 2007 - time to update?

Comment: Yeah, sadly we still have to support it for business reasons.

Comment: My final goal was to build jdk11 on CentOS5. So I worked around this problem by commenting out references to fallocate64. Then I used jdk9 to build jdk10 and then jdk11. I used GCC 4.8.2, Beanutils 2.18 and other dependencies from https://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/5/x86_64/RPMS/ to build OpenJDK 11 on CentOS5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Building JDK requires at least GCC 5.0 (see [Building the JDK: CC](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openjdk/jdk/master/doc/building.html#gcc)).
2. This seems to be a problem in the glibc version (see [redhat-issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=500487), [util-linux](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-816003-start-0.html)). So, updating your glibc to the latest version might solve it.
3. If you don't want to update your system's glibc, here is another alternative:

By looking at the man page of [fallocate](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html), we find that the description mentions that [posix_fallocate(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_fallocate.3.html) is a portable, POSIX.1-specified version of it, in case the `mode` parameter has the default value (0). The same applies to `fallocate64`.
Since all the occurrences of the aforementioned error already use the default `mode` value, you can replace them with `posix_fallocate64()` (instead of commenting them out as you mentioned in another comment).

The denoted man page says that:

> This default behavior [of `fallocate` with `mode`=0] closely resembles the
> behavior of the posix_fallocate(3) library function, and is intended
> as a method of optimally implementing that function.